# Routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails.I am following [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial. I've built a basic form which takes `title` and `text` as an input and stores in the database.
Here is my code:

**ArticlesController:**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'welcome/index'
   root 'welcome#index'
   resources :articles
end
```

**new.html.erb(the form):**

```
<h1>New article</h1>
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
 <%= form.label :title %><br>
 <%= form.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :text %><br>
  <%= form.text_area :text %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.submit %>
</p>
```

After I click submit button of the form, I am taken to the `show` view where I display the data of the form. But I am not able to understand how exactly this is happening? Nowhere have I mentioned to render the `show.html` view, so how does Rails understand which view I have to render? I am a bit confused with this.

Note: I come from a Django background, so how I would implement routing in Django is by defining the required method(from `views.py`) in my `urls.py` for the corresponding route. Then I would render the template defined in the method in `views.py`.

Comment: The `resources :articles` takes care of routing to proper controller/methods. As for rendering the `show.html`, if the controller finds a `#method.htmll` file in views, it will automatically render that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `resources :articles` on your **config/routes.rb** file which is a rails helper method that generates the following routes when you run `rake routes | grep articles` on your terminal shell

```
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                                   articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                                                   articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                               articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                          articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                               articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                                               articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                               articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                               articles#destroy
```

The statement `redirect_to @article` at the end of `def create ... end` block is translated by rails to 'redirect_to /articles/@article.id' which is responsible for redirecting the response to `articles#show` action defined in **app/controllers/articles_controller.rb**

Answer (score 0):

> rails g scaffold article title:string text:string

run above command and you will get complete application what you are looking for.
You will understand what is needed in routes.

Answer (score 0):

Please complete the routes guide

But for now as

```
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)
```

and in your create action in the last line you wrote

```
redirect_to @article
```

which leads to you to the **/articles/:id** of the instance variable **@article**

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
 def create
          @article = Article.new(article_params)
          @article.save
         redirect_to @article
      end
```

after @article is successfully saved, you are redirecting it to show action by specifying **redirect_to @article**

If you do **rake routes**

```
    article GET    /article/:id(.:format)      articles#show
```

so the actual route for show action is article_path(@article).You can redirect to the show action by writing  **redirect_to article_path(@article)**  or even if you simply pass an object (@article) to redirect_to method, rails will redirect it to the corresponding show action because of syntactic sugar of redirect_to url_for(@page)